# How can i get an every third and every fourth element from list in bash?

Tags: arrays, macos, bash, indexing

I have next list in my script

```
....
declare -a Issues=('DPTESTXXXX-15-' 'DPTESTXXXX-16-' 'DPTESTXXXX-17-' 'DPTESTXXXX-18-' 'DPTESTXXXX-19-' 'DPTESTXXXX-20-' 'DPTESTXXXX-21-' 'DPTESTXXXX-22-' 'DPTESTXXXX-23-' 'DPTESTXXXX-24-' 'DPTESTXXXX-25-' 'DPTESTXXXX-26-' 'DPTESTXXXX-27-' 'DPTESTXXXX-28-');
for i in ${Issues[@]}; do
    git checkout -b "$i"'do-this-rc1'    
    ....
done
```

So in output i had a new git branches with names DPTESTXXXX-'numbers'-do-this-rc1 for all elements in list.
Now i need the same i.e.  `-> git checkout -b "$i"'do-this-**rc1**'` ,  but only for every third element in list.
And `-> git checkout -b "$i"'do-this-**rc2**'` for every fourth element. 
What is the best way to do this in bash?

Comment: Do you need to operate on the third/fourth entries in the same loop? Or do you need to loop over every third entry and then separately loop over every fourth entry?

Comment: @ Etan Reisner , actually doesn't matter, but this script is quite big indeed  so i need as 'light' solution as possible .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood this corretly, you want to select every 3 entries and every 4 entries to run the git command. This may be what you need, check it out:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a Issues=( 'DPTESTXXXX-15-'
                    'DPTESTXXXX-16-'
                    'DPTESTXXXX-17-'
                    'DPTESTXXXX-18-'
                    'DPTESTXXXX-19-'
                    'DPTESTXXXX-20-'
                    'DPTESTXXXX-21-'
                    'DPTESTXXXX-22-'
                    'DPTESTXXXX-23-'
                    'DPTESTXXXX-24-'
                    'DPTESTXXXX-25-'
                    'DPTESTXXXX-26-'
                    'DPTESTXXXX-27-'
                    'DPTESTXXXX-28-' );

for((n=0;n<${#Issues[@]};n++)); do
        if (( $(($n % 3 )) == 0 )); then
                # Run every 3 entries
                git checkout -b "${Issues[$n]}"'do-this-rc1'
        fi
        if (( $((n % 4 )) == 0 )); then
                # Run every 4 entries
                git checkout -b "${Issues[$n]}"'do-this-rc2'
        fi
done
```